# compare two text files and append only the differences to one

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm writing a program under macOS that logs into a website's chatroom, scrapes the contents, writes it to a file and formats it. It works well (albeit slowly), but it will only scrape the way the chatroom looks at the runtime. What I want to do is append the differences.

One way I thought about doing this (hence the title) was to have a master file and a temp file. The master file always exists, and the temp file just gets written to then compared to the master. The two files are compared, and whatever differences exist between the two are copied from the temp to the master. I am open to other solutions, but this seems like a feasible one. The files will always live locally, and the program will also be run locally.

I am not sure where to begin with it. My code is below. I know that it is messy and in need of revision; I am still a beginner with Python.

```
import mechanize
import fileinput
import re
from os import chdir
from os import environ
from time import strftime

home = environ['HOME']
file = "ChatLog_" + strftime("%F") + ".txt"
filename = home + "/" + file
chdir(home + '/Desktop/')

# get login forms
def select_form(form):
    return form.attrs.get('id', None) == 'auth' 

#  authenticate and log raw chat    
def auth():
        br = mechanize.Browser()
        br.set_handle_robots(False)
        br.open('http://website.com/endpoint')
        br.select_form(predicate=select_form)
        br.form['name'] = "username"
        br.form['pass'] = "password"
        br.submit()
        text_file = open(filename, 'w')
        response = br.response().read()
        text_file.write(response)
        text_file.close()

n = 0
while n < 9999:
    try:
        auth()

        # strip first line
        with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
            data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
        with open(filename, 'w') as fout:
            fout.writelines(data[2:])

        # strip nbsp characters 
        with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
            text = f.read()
            text = re.sub('&nbsp;', '', text)
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(text)
            f.truncate()

        # strip #039 apostrophe characters
        with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
            text = f.read()
            text = re.sub('&#039;', '\'', text)
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(text)
            f.truncate()

        # strip everything that lives in and around brackets, i.e. HTML tags
        with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
            text = f.read()
            text = re.sub('<.*?>', '', text)
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(text)
            f.truncate()

        n = n + 1
        print(n)
    except KeyboardInterrupt: print("\nUser aborted."); quit()
```

Comment: look into `comm` unix util maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ping the site continuously and don't mind skipping over duplicate lines (can you safely assume that users won't generally write the exact same thing?) one quick way you can go about this is store the results of your scrape in sets. Then by taking either their [symmetric difference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference) or [difference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference) you can see where they differ. The version you use would depend on which logic you want to apply:

> **difference(*others)**
>   `set - other - ...` 
>   Return a new set with elements in the set that are *not in the others.*
>
> **symmetric_difference(other)**
>   `set ^ other` 
>   Return a new set with elements in *either the set or other* but not both.

Example:

```
 old_lines=['chat1', 'chat2']
 new_lines = ['chat1', 'chat2', 'chat3']
 set(old_lines) ^ set(new_lines)
```

Outputs `{'chat3'}`. If you also care about the order of the diffs, just replace set with [OrderedSet](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694-orderedset/)

---

If you decide to go with diffing files, the python standard library has difflib. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.unified_diff)

```
>>> s1 = ['bacon\n', 'eggs\n', 'ham\n', 'guido\n']
>>> s2 = ['python\n', 'eggy\n', 'hamster\n', 'guido\n']
>>> for line in unified_diff(s1, s2, fromfile='before.py', tofile='after.py'):
...     sys.stdout.write(line)   
--- before.py
+++ after.py
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-bacon
-eggs
-ham
+python
+eggy
+hamster
 guido
```

Comment: wouldn't you want the regular difference? take the lines from the newly generated data and remove any that are already in the master?  Otherwise things that are already in the master but not in the new stuff would be re-written to the file.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Is there such a method? In the above case he can for sure keep the + lines. However some chats also allow deletions, so it might prove useful

Comment: subtraction: `{'a','b','c','d'} - {'a','b','H'} == {'c','d'}` and in the case of deletion `master` would hold lines that did not appear in `new` so they would be in the symmetric difference and you would write them to `master`? That still seems like the wrong outcome.

Comment: First set is new file right? Symmetric difference would give the "true" differences, namely {'H','c','d'} however the information about the action producing each element (insert, delete) ,is lost. And if he wants to keep only additions, you do have a point. See edit

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally got a chance to sit down with using `set`. Unfortunately it is a bit tricky with comparing files, and I'm having trouble getting `set` to play nice with my file. This looks ugly and doesn't output right: `set(open(filepathVarable).read())` prints `set(['\n', ' ', "'", '&', '*', '-', ',', '/', '.', '1', '0', '3', '2', '5', '4', '7', '6', '9', '8', ';', ':', ...` ... Could you expand your examples to demonstrate `set` with multi-line files?

Comment: @celestialroad try opening files like so: `with open(filename) as f:
lines = set(f.readlines())` . This will get you a set holding each line, for which the first example is already provided. If you open using `read()` then the whole contents are loaded into a string and when you apply the `set()` to it, it will add to it every letter as an element, instead of every line.

Comment: Excellent, @themistoklik, I think this solution will work well for my purposes. Thanks.